# Can I have one Repo for client which contains all repos for that client?

Tags: git, github, version-control, release-management

I have multiple clients and have multiple projects for each client. Some of the projects are forks of core projects in my GitHub.

I wanted to know the best way to structure this. Can I create one client repo, and then add all the repos for that client into directories inside the client repo? I would like to be able to pull updates from the core repos when necessary as well as have branches for each repo that's in each subdirectory.

Would I have to create a repo per client per project? I would like to avoid this because it can get messy because of the number of repositories I would have to create. Some of these repos are microapps so they have some common code as well. From my understanding, I can create subtrees on the core repository of the common code.

I'm not an expert in Github but am learning a lot and would like to make sure I structure everything correctly from the beginning. To avoid technical debt and all that jazz.

Comment: This is probably a release management and configuration issue; not what Git does, but what people often try to use it for. What sort of changes are in the per-client forks?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to structure this is to not have to fork code for each client. Forking per client is a maintenance nightmare.

Rather than trying to solve this with version control, it is better solved with release and configuration management.

---

Instead of writing special code per client, have your code use [environment variables](https://12factor.net/config), configuration files, and asset directories. Then each client has their own configuration files and assets.

For example, let's say you have projects A and B. Project A gets its own repo. Project B gets its own repo. Manage these like regular software releases.

A needs secret keys from environment variables. B has customizable images and strings.

When you have a client which wants to use B, make them a repo for only their configuration files and assets.

```
client1.git
  B.config
  assets/
    b/
      logo.png
```

Install A and B for the client. Install their config files and assets. Add their secret keys for A to their environment variables.

---

If a client really needs special code you can gate it behind a configuration setting. If it's really client specific, write a plugin for the client.

Comment: There are more files that can be customized as well as added to the microapps. This would be a good structure for when the client wants the micro app as is with only the configuration files as there customizations. How would I approach this if I also need to customize files specifically for the client?

Comment: @ElCree Make it so those customizations, and only those customizations, are in per client repositories. Or make them as generic as possible in their own repos to be shared. It's difficult to talk about this in the abstract. Could you give examples of the kind of customizations?